# Caching mechanism of DataLoader in graphql for DotNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, .net-core, graphql, dataloader

//Sample Query

```
        Field<XYZType, XYZ>()
        .Name("xyz")
        .Argument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("param1", "desc")//Query parameter
        .Argument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("param2", "desc")//Query parameter
        .Description("Get all data")
          .ResolveAsync(ctx =>
          {
              IDataLoader<XYZ> loader = accessor.Context.GetOrAddLoader("xyz",
              () => APiCall(param1, param2);
              return loader.LoadAsync();
          });
```

From the official documents, it's been specified that GetOrAddLoader provides caching mechanism without batching. But usually, an id is provided in the LoadAsync() function. 
So how does caching work if my data comes from an external API call?